# Script allowed to launch without sudo password works in console, but not in .desktop file, and pkexec issues

Tags: command-line, sudo, password, .desktop, pkexec

I have set in `/etc/sudoers.d/qgis_2_18` a script to be launched without `sudo` password:

```bsh
marco ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/marco/Dropbox/bin/qgis_2_18
```

Content of `/home/marco/Dropbox/bin/qgis_2_18`:

```bsh
xhost local:root
sudo docker container start hardcore_yonath
xhost -
```

It works from bash, but it does not work if invoked from a .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=QGIS Desktop 2.18
GenericName=Geographic Information System 2.18
Icon=qgis
TryExec=/home/marco/Dropbox/bin/qgis_2_18
Exec=/home/marco/Dropbox/bin/qgis_2_18
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Qt;Education;Science;Geography;
Keywords=map;globe;postgis;wms;wfs;ogc;osgeo;
StartupWMClass=QGIS3
```

With `Terminal=false`, nothing happens. With `Terminal=true`, a bash is displayed and the password is asked.

Furthermore, this works with `sudo`, not with `pkexec`. It seems `pkexec` does not honor the `sudoers` rules. Is this a know bug or is intentional?

I use ***L***ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Show us: the `/etc/sudoers.d/` script, the `.desktop` file, the invoked script, ... . Also, your 2nd Q (`sudo` vs `pkexec`) belongs in a Question of its own. If it were to be answered here, we couldn't find it from your Title. Remember to Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1153646/edit ) your post, and use the formatting tools, line '{}'.

Comment: @waltinator: done